# @IBDesignable - view not rendering as expected

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom `UIView` subclass that I am trying to render using `@IBDesignable`.

I have an`@IBInspectable` property named `image`, which I set from the interface builder.

When I open the interface builder the `image` that I choose is not rendered properly in the view, that is, it looks like some trouble with autolayout.
When I checked the `Report navigator` I am getting a warning in the `Interface Builder` group.

```
Showing All Messages
(null): -pie being ignored. It is only used when linking a main executable
```

This happens under the `Link <IBDESIGNABLE_EXECUTABLE>` section.

I have no idea how to fix this. Tried many solutions from [SO](http://stackoverflow.com). Cleaning build folder, clearing derived data etc. Nothing worked.

Please provide your valuable comments or a solution to this problem. Thanks! :)

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @Rob I could zero in to the problem.

**What I have:**

An `IBDesignable` `UIView` Subclass with properties:

- an`@IBInspectable` property named `image`.
- an ImageView
- a ScrollView

I initialise and add the ScrollView and ImageViews as subviews using

```
required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initialiseImageView()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    initialiseImageView()
}
```

**Problem:**

In `initialiseImageView()`:
 I add the `scrollView` as subview of the `UIView` and `ImageView` as the subview of the `scrollView` to use the `viewForZooming` delegate. I also add constraints to keep the views in place.
The problem is when I use:

```
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

If I use this I get autolayout warnings at runtime. But the `imageView` is misplaced in `interface builder`, although the image is rendered correctly.

If I comment the same, everything is as expected in `interface builder`. But the UI breaks at runtime due to `AutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`.

---

I have the code in [github](https://github.com/radhakrishnapai/RKImageView). I am trying the latter approach mentioned in [TN2154](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2154/_index.html)

I am setting all `AutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to be false and adding the constraints for the subviews in the code itself. The constraints for the `UIView` subclass are added in the interface builder directly and no warnings exist as of now. The code works as expected at runtime also. The `IBDesignable` part is the one that is not working as expected.

---

Strangely enough, When I removed the line

```
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

everything is working perfectly. The error that I used to get at runtime is now gone. I don't know if something else that I did fixed it. Thanks a lot for helping to pin point the issue @Rob.

Comment: Please update your GitHub link to a specific commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BTW, I just did a quick `@IBDesignable` with an `@IBInspectable` that was a `UIImage` and a `draw(rect:)` that rendered that image and it worked fine:

```
@IBDesignable class CustomView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var image: UIImage?

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        image?.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)
    }

}
```

When I do that in a separate target (as one should with designables), I also see the same warning:

> ld: warning: -pie being ignored. It is only used when linking a main executable

I suspect that warning may be a red herring. The `man` pages for `ld` described `-pie` option as follows:

> This makes a special kind of main executable that is position independent (PIE).

You can toggle this setting if you go to the link settings for your designables' target and change the "Generate Position-Dependent Executable" in the "Linking" settings. Then that warning will go away. Personally, I've never noticed that warning and never changed this settings, and never noticed any adverse affects, but if you want to confirm this for your own sense of satisfaction, try changing this setting and see if you can get the warning to go away.

Bottom line, your `@IBDesignable` problem probably rests elsewhere, but it's hard to diagnose on the basis of the information provided. We need more information (or, ideally, a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

---

It's hard to comment on your autolayout warnings without seeing what those warning are, but I'd guess that (a) you're adding a subview; but (b) not setting the constraints for said subview; and therefore (c) that when you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, that your constraints are ambiguous and therefore result in error messages and unexpected layout at runtime. Or maybe it's a symptom of the idiosyncrasies of scroll views. But it's hard to say without seeing (a) actual autolayout error; (b) what subviews your `@IBDesignable` added; and (c) what constraints you added for your subviews.

Bottom line, make sure that your programmatically added subviews have all of their constraints unambiguously defined. Also remember that constraints for scrollview subviews act differently that many constraints, defining the contentSize of the scroll view rather than the size of the subviews. (On this latter point, see [TN2154](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2154/_index.html).)

Comment: Thanks @Rob. You are right. That warning is totally unrelated to my designable problem. Let me just look into the problem again and I will provide you with the MCVE after.

Comment: I have the code in [github](https://github.com/radhakrishnapai/RKImageView). I am trying the latter approach mentioned in [TN2154](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2154/_index.html).

Comment: I am setting all AutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to be false and adding the constraints for the subviews in the code itself. The constraints for the UIView subclass are added in the interface builder directly and no warnings exist as of now. The code works as expected at runtime also. The IBDesignable part is the one that is not working as expected

Comment: Strangely enough, When I removed the line `self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, everything is working perfectly. The error that I used to get at runtime is now gone. I don't know if something else that I did fixed it. Thanks a lot for helping to pin point the issue @Rob.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I deleted some no longer existing ibdesignable variables.

They were stuck in the User defined runtime attributes.

Deleting that, and then cleaning build folder, rebuilding resolved this for me!